# Activity crashes when more than one picture is loaded

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview

I have developed a code which will create a ImageView dynamically and place it on the screen. But when i test it on the emulator many imageview are created, but while testing on phone only one imageView is created and second time the application crashes. Here's the code. While usb debugging on my cell when I create one ImageView, after that to add other Image to image view On click of button gallery is opened to select other image, but when other image is selected the last imageview is delete. I think that when the gallery is opened the activity is started again. Can someone please tell me where am i going wrong.

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

public class DragActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    ImageView imgView;
    private int nfontSize;
    Bitmap originalBitmap, image;
    int height1, width1;
    final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;
    Uri selectedImage;
    Bitmap yourSelectedImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int nImageId = intent.getIntExtra("drawableId", 0);
        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewEdit);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(nImageId);

        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drag_activity_layout);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        // Dimension x,y of device to create a scaled bitmap having similar
        // dimnstinos to screen size
        height1 = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        width1 = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
                if (yourSelectedImage != null) {
                    final DragImageView dynamicImgView = new DragImageView(
                            getApplicationContext(), yourSelectedImage);
                    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    dynamicImgView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    relativeLayout.addView(dynamicImgView);
                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    void saveImage(Bitmap bmpImg) {
        String RootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + AppConstant.SavedFolderName;
        File myDir = new File(RootDir);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Invite-"+ n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir,fname);
        if(file.exists())file.delete();
        try{
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Toast.makeText(DragActivity.this,
                    "Image saved to folder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            bmpImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_addText:
            final Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(this);
            alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Add Text");

            String[] colors = { "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "BLACK", "WHITE",
                    "YELLOW", "CYAN" };
            String[] fonts = { "Wedding", "Birthday", "Events", "Business" };
            // set custom dialog components
            final EditText etUserTxt = (EditText) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.editText_userTxt);
            final TextView tvFontSize = (TextView) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_fontsize);
            final TextView tvErrorMsg = (TextView) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_errorTxt);

            Button btnOk = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
            Button btnCancel = (Button) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
            final Spinner colorSpinner = (Spinner) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.spinnerColor);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
            colorSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            final Spinner fontFaceSpinner = (Spinner) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.spinnerFontFace);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFont = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fonts);
            fontFaceSpinner.setAdapter(adapterFont);

            SeekBar seekBar_fontSize = (SeekBar) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            nfontSize = 20;

            fontFaceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Typeface tf;
                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AnkeCalligraph.TTF");
                        tvFontSize.setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/LucidaBrightRegular.ttf");
                        tvFontSize.setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Subway.ttf");
                        tvFontSize.setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/timesbi.ttf");
                        tvFontSize.setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    default:
                        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/LucidaBrightRegular.ttf");
                        tvFontSize.setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            seekBar_fontSize
                    .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            tvFontSize.setTextSize(progress);
                            nfontSize = progress;
                        }
                    });

            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String userTxt = etUserTxt.getText().toString();
                    int colorId = colorSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    int fontId = fontFaceSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    final DragView textView = new DragView(
                            getApplicationContext());
                    textView.setText(userTxt);
                    textView.setTextSize(nfontSize);
                    switch (colorId) {
                    case 0:
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    Typeface tf;
                    switch (fontId) {
                    case 0:
                        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AnkeCalligraph.TTF");
                        textView.setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/LucidaBrightRegular.ttf");
                        textView.setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Subway.ttf");
                        textView.setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/timesbi.ttf");
                        textView.setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    default:
                        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/LucidaBrightRegular.ttf");
                        textView.setTypeface(tf);
                        break;
                    }
                    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    relativeLayout.addView(textView, params);
                    if (userTxt.isEmpty()) {
                        tvErrorMsg.setText("Please enter the text");
                        tvErrorMsg.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        tvErrorMsg.setTextSize(20);
                    } else {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }

            });

            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_savePicture:

            View v = findViewById(R.id.drag_activity_layout);
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();

            saveImage(b);

            return true;
        case R.id.action_addImage:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                    SELECT_IMAGE);

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public static int getFilesCount(File file) {

        int count = 0;
        if(file != null){
            Log.d("File Check","File is not empty");
        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        for (File f : files)
            if (f.isDirectory())
                count += getFilesCount(f);
            else
                count++;
        }
        else{
            Log.d("File Check","File is not empty");
            return 0;}
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: put your log cat code.

Comment: I ran the apk but their was no error displayed in Log

Comment: `and second time the application crashes.` when we have crash, we have errors too.

Comment: I have installed the apk on phone and then tested it so no log cat

Comment: You can download an app like "Alogcat" (  https://play.google.com/store/search?q=alogcat&hl=de ), with this App you can read your Logcat directly on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line creats the error:

```
final DragImageView dynamicImgView = new DragImageView(
                        getApplicationContext(), yourSelectedImage);
```

My first suggestion is that you try to declare the variable (dynamicImgView) a secound time, when you ran your code for the secound time. The variable is already there because it has an referece to the relative layout it is added to:

```
relativeLayout.addView(dynamicImgView);
```

My secound seggestion is that the variable can not be changed the secound time, because it is declared with the "final" keyword.

Source: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29)

I know the variable shouldn't be there after you leave the function (because then you are out of the validity range of this variable), but because of the referece to the RelativeLayout i think it is still there for the System.

May this will help you =).

Best regards
Tim.